# Detect when smart watches are visiting a web page

Tags: javascript, php, user-tracking

Smart watches are getting web browsers and although it may not be the optimal device to use to browse the web a few people will probably use them. What I would like to do is to detect if someone visits a web page with a smart watch.

I would like to do this with either PHP or javascript or a combination of the two.

How could I check to be mostly sure that it is a smart watch visiting the web page?

Comment: Probably the same way you check if a mobile browser is watching (with minor changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen size and user agent are the two most common routes for detection.  User agent would depend on the watch.

Comment: Is there a list of user agents and screen sizes? When considering a smart watch I thought an easy way may be to look at a max width/height and the proportions to be fairly square. Or would it be better to check for exact sizes? (I would like to act on the information as soon as the user has loaded the page)

Comment: There is really never a complete list of user agents, as these change from year to year.  The most reliable approach is probably to go by screen size if possible.  I think checking absolute size would be the most reliable (number of pixels).

Comment: It seems easy to possibly confuse a smart watch with an older phone as current smart watches are having resolutions that are around 320px in width. checking if the resolution seems to be a square would be viable as the Sony Smartwatch 3 comes in at 320x320 but others like the Samsung Gear S comes in at 360x480

Comment: I suppose the question would be, is this for responsive design or marketing?  For responsive design, the same layout would work on old devices or watches.  For marketing, the only route is to collect a list of User Agents you want to target, and match the string patterns.  Still, this won't ever be 100% reliable, as eventually we will see chrome and firefox running on a watch.